# Calculating actual width of element in css or styled component or scss

Tags: css, sass

Suppose we have min-width: 3rem in a div element initially. But when we add more contents in div, width of a div increases. Now is there any tricks to calculate actual width of that div in css or scss or styled component.

Answer (score 0):

There is variable feature in CSS to allow developers use variable width/height in native CSS, example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Nested_calc_with_CSS_Variables), note also the use of [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) attribute function:

```css
.foo {
  --widthA: 100px;
  --widthB: calc(var(--widthA) / 2);
  --widthC: calc(var(--widthB) / 2);
  width: var(--widthC);
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: var(--widthA)
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
```

My answer here is for CSS, so you can just have your width (or event height, font-size, padding, margin ... etc) pre-defined in a variable and use `calc()` to calculate the value for your attribute, 
for SASS you can refer to the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables).

also good to have a look at [compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) for CSS variables.